# Добавить единый текст ко всем товарам в битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, cms

Есть один текст (единый) который надо добавить во все товары

То есть можно добавить под описанием блок, например: Обязательно ознакомится

и там этот единый текст уже вставить.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Копируете шаблон компоненты **bitrix:catalog** или просто детальной страницы **bitrix:catalog.element** в шаблон сайта (возможно уже скопированы). В шаблоне компонента **bitrix:catalog.element** находите нужное место для вставки, например после вывода детального текста товара и вставляете код верстки вашего текста. После сброса кеша, текст сразу же появится. К сожалению, на пальцах тут текстом расписать что и как делать, не выйдет - слишком много факторов и пояснений.

Вот тут [документация по компонентам](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04565&LESSON_PATH=3913.4565) для разработчика.

**Второй вариант**, это добавить текст на все страницы каталога. Это проще, но на всех страницах: Заходите на страницу каталога, нажимаете в полоске администратора "Изменить страницу" и после кода компоненты Каталога вставляете свой текст.

**Внимание**! Пробуйте сделать на копии сайта или не боевом сервере! Ну или хотя бы сделайте бэкап сайта, на случай если поломаете чего-нибудь.